# How can $\cot(\theta)$ be integrated to give $\log(\sin(\theta))+\log(2c)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In the book differential equations by George F Simmons , the author integrates $$\dfrac{dr}{r}=\dfrac{\cos \theta d\theta }{\sin \theta }$$ to get $$ \log(r)=\log(\sin(\theta))+\log(2c) $$. I understand where the left hand side of the equation comes from but I can't wrap my head around where the $$ \log(\sin(\theta))+\log(2c)$$ comes from. Can somebody please help me understand this? I get that they used the fact that integral of $1/x$ gives $\ln|x|$ but I dont really understand why that works for $\cot(\theta)$.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{dr}{r}=\dfrac{\cos \theta d\theta }{\sin \theta }$$
Note that you have:
$$\dfrac {d \sin \theta}{d \theta}=\cos \theta \implies d\sin \theta =\cos \theta d \theta$$
Then:
$$\int \dfrac{\cos \theta d\theta }{\sin \theta }=\int \dfrac{d \sin \theta }{\sin \theta }=\ln ( \sin \theta)+C$$
You can also write the constant $C$ as $\ln c$ if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\dfrac{\cos \theta d\theta }{\sin \theta }=\cot{\theta}d\theta,\implies\int\cot{\theta}d\theta=\ln|\sin\theta|+C.
$$
Therefore, $\log(2c)$ is a misprint.

Comment: I get it thanks. I had forgotten the integral of $cot(x)$, sorry for the dumb question. The $ln(2c)$ is actually not a misprint i believe, the author has multiplied 2 there as to make the final equation to be $r=2c•sin(\theta)$ which is the required final equation

Comment: $\log 2c$ isn't a misprint, it's how the author has decided to write the constant of interration.

Comment: The way it is written might be intentional for something later.